# reverseGeocodeLocation country list

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, reverse-geocoding, mkreversegeocoder

I'm creating a global app and one of the initial screens will detect which country the user is in. I'm using `reverseGeocodeLocation` for this.

```
[geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:[locations lastObject] completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error)
     {
         CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks lastObject];
         country = placemark.country;
         [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];

         if (country != NULL) {
             [self showAlert];
         }
         else {
             [self showActionSheet];
         }
     }];
```

When in the UK `placemark.country` will return "United Kingdom". I'm trying to find a list of the return strings for each country. I couldn't find anything on the apple documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You could write code in 2 minutes to get the list for yourself, iterate through the list of ISO country codes and then convert them from an ISO code to the country name and NSLog each one.

The name displayed would of course only be the name for the current language locale setting on your device, in your case English.